# Using alternative label for Solr 4.0 Multivalue-field

Tags: solr, label, facet

I'm struggeling a little about the label of my facet-fields. I'm using Solr4 and feed my solr-index with the drupal-solr-search-api-modul (http://drupal.org/project/search_api_solr‎).

I use some taxonomy-fields for facets and almost everything is working finde. But I can't change the label of the fields. Maybe say, I have the field

```
"sm_thisisvocname"
```

Then the field is in the index like

```
sm_thisisvocname:name
```

for the values of the field and

```
sm_thisisvocname:vocabulary:name
```

for the label of the (taxonomy)-field like "This Is Vocname".

So the XML looks

```
<lst name="facet_fields">
<lst name="sm_thisisvocname:name">
<int name="C">2</int>
<int name="B">1</int>
<int name="D">1</int>
<int name="E">1</int>
</lst>
</lst>
```

AND

```
<sm_thisisvocname:vocabulary:name>This Is Vocname</sm_thisisvocname:vocabulary:name>
```

in the xml. I can't I use the query

```
&facet=true&facet.field=sm_thisisvocname:name
```

because there colons in the field-names ... Can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you also add your schema.xml?

Comment: Hi Junai, thanks for your interest. I paste my schema.xml, is this okay?

Comment: sorry, here we go: http://pastebin.com/873VZC0c I use the drupal-Standard-Scheme

Answer (score 1):

you should change your field name to not have the `colon :` as it is treated as a special character for multiple things in solr query.

Could only find the [Documentation](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/lweug/Dynamic+Fields):-

```
Currently a field name must consist of only A-Z, a-z, 0-9, - or _
```

[Field Alias](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#Field_alias) is something that you can check upon, however it too depends on :)

You can also try to escape the `:` in the field name.